# Media Query. Without using !important

Tags: css

[image]

> Hi can anyone help me with this I'm having a problem when it comes to
> a media query CSS. I'm trying to make my div 70% on certain width of
> the screen. However, when checking it on the browser it's not working.
> But, when I'm using !important it's working fine. However, my goal is
> not to use !important. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: cause when using important I'm having a problem when I called again the class on lowest width of the screen.

Comment: in style sheet put the media query AFTER the regular css

Comment: Hi thanks looking into it now

Comment: I would move the regular css into another media query with different parameters (i.e., max-width: 1200px)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In CSS, rules are overridden by rules *with the same specificity* occurring later in the same stylesheet (and in document-order when multiple external stylesheets are loaded into a HTML document or with `@import`).
- Now, consider that:

  - Your `@query`-wrapped rule is on line 2679.
  - Your "normal" rule is on lines 3110 and 3157.
  - Therefore your normal rules will always override the `@query` rule because it has the same specificity unless you use `!important`.
- Therefore, either:

  - Make the `@query` rule more specific. or...
  - Keep on using `!important`. or...
  - Move your `@query` rules to the bottom of your stylesheet.